# AngularJS e angular 2, 4,6

Tags: angularjs, angular

Eu ainda posso usar o AngularJS?

Eu quero usar ele pra coisa mais simples, exemplo é filtrar uma lista, e não quero instalar npm, nodeJS, angular CLI ou usar estrutura MVC pra isso.

Eu posso usar ele ou ele vai ser "desligado"?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status

Comment: Então tenho mais 3 anos de certeza? e oq acha?

Comment: Eu acho nada não.

Comment: Eu não usaria não, mesmo que pra aprendizado. Quer aprender alguma tecnologia nova? Estude o [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar com tranquilidade. O código fonte sempre estará lá no github(ou qualquer plataforma que for migrado). Mas, alguns pontos básicos que se devem levar em consideração:

- Em uma postagem no Blog, eles avisaram sobre o lançamento de uma versão LTS, com suporte de 3 anos e após isso, não haverá mais desenvolvimento deles. Ou seja, não haverá correção de Bugs, nem correção de problemas de segurança. Para ler a postagem no Blog, só clicar [aqui](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c)
- Para fazer algo pessoal, você pode usar qualquer tecnologia que esteja mais familiarizado, então dependendo do contexto, você pode usar qualquer ferramenta sem se preocupar muito com questões de suporte.
- Você também deve levar em consideração, se o caso de precisar desenvolver algo, não é uma oportunidade para que aprenda novas ferramentas. Para coisas pequenas, temos o Vue.js, por exemplo, e já existe uma demanda no mercado por ele.

E respondendo a sua pergunta de maneira direta: Sim, você pode usar o Angular. Ele não será desligado, apenas parará de receber atualizações em Julho de 2021.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu perguntei sobre o angularJS porque achei a aprendizagem facil (VueJS também não parece dificil) e tenho um material bom sobre ele

Comment: De nada. É bom aprender coisas novas, mas nada de errado em querer fazer algo mais rápido já usando o que sabe. Ás vezes a gente só quer fazer uma tabela pra consultar algo com mais facilidade, ou coisas do tipo, casa perfeitamente com o caso de usar coisas já conhecidas. Ah, e não esquece de marcar a questão como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Para sua necessidade, o angulaJS atenderia sem problemas. Mesmo acabando o em 2018 as releases dele, o framework 1.x é útil e funcional para coisas simples.
Caso depois queira aprofundar em novas tecnologias e aprender novas ferramentas, não haveria problema algum.